# Most efficient way to select corresponding value in another column for MIN(column)

Tags: mysql, syntax, greatest-n-per-group

Based on this data:

```
create table wp_posts (
  ID integer primary key auto_increment,
  post_title varchar(30),
  post_type varchar(30)
);

create table wp_postmeta (
  ID integer primary key auto_increment,
  post_id integer,
  meta_key varchar(30) not null default '_regular_price',
  meta_value integer not null
);

insert into wp_posts (post_title, post_type) values
('Apple Pie','Product'),
('French Toast','Product'),
('Shepards Pie','Product'),
('Jam Pie','Product'),
('Jam Pie','Product'),
('Plate','Not a Product'),
('Bucket','Not a Product'),
('Chequebook','Not a Product'),
('French Toast','Product'),
('French Toast','Product'),
('Banana','Product'),
('Banana','Product'),
('Banana','Product');

insert into wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_value) values
(1,10),
(2,5),
(3,9),
(4,8),
(5,11),
(6,12),
(7,10),
(8,6),
(9,1),
(10,1),
(11,2),
(12,1),
(13,7);
```

This SQL query

```
SELECT wp_posts.post_title, MIN(wp_postmeta.meta_value)                            
FROM   wp_postmeta 
JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' 
  AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 
GROUP BY wp_posts.post_title
```

will give

```
+--------------+-----------------------------+
|  post_title  | MIN(wp_postmeta.meta_value) |
+--------------+-----------------------------+
| Apple Pie    |                          10 |
| French Toast |                           1 |
| Shepards Pie |                           9 |
| Jam Pie      |                           8 |
| Banana       |                           1 |
+--------------+-----------------------------+
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fa38dd4e21395ad3855cf880a65afc2a

However, I also want the corresponding value in the rows for another column, `wp_posts.post_id` (unique).  How would I include this in the SELECT efficiently?

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Tell us the query you would ideally like to be able to run here.

Comment: If `wp_postmeta.post_id` is unique, then using the `MIN()` function in your query is rather useless.

Comment: Well it's required in the SQL standards to write correct ANSI SQL GROUP BY queries like that.. If you have MySQL 8.0 making better [Optimizer Statistics](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizer-statistics.html) and making a [HISTOGRAM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html) on the columns post_title and post_id it might work out better.. [Here](https://mysqlserverteam.com/histogram-statistics-in-mysql/) is explainment how it works..

Comment: What mysql version you have?

Comment: @Arjan he want the post_id associated to the `MIN(meta_value)`

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza I would like a solution that works for MySQL 5+.

Answer (score 2):

use row_number() window function

```
select ID,post_title,post_type,meta_value from 
(SELECT wp_postmeta.ID,post_title,post_type ,meta_value,
row_number()over(partition by post_title order by wp_postmeta.meta_value) rn                           
FROM   wp_postmeta 
JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' 
  AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 

) t where t.rn=1
```

Comment: I might have just found that out the hard way...  Unfortunately my testing and production environments are different, testing uses Server version: 10.1.37-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution, production uses SQL 5.  Does anyone have an alternative?

Comment: Would it be safe for me to upgrade to MariaDB 10.2?  I can do that from within WHM.  I just host a WordPress/Woocommerce website on my server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MAX(wp_posts.id)`:

```
SELECT MAX(wp_posts.id) AS post_id, wp_posts.post_title, MIN(wp_postmeta.meta_value)                            
FROM   wp_postmeta 
JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' 
  AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 
GROUP BY wp_posts.post_title
```

> ```
> post_id | post_title   | MIN(wp_postmeta.meta_value)
> ------: | :----------- | --------------------------:
>       1 | Apple Pie    |                          10
>      10 | French Toast |                           1
>       3 | Shepards Pie |                           9
>       5 | Jam Pie      |                           8
>      13 | Banana       |                           1
> ```